# robot-framework click button not found but can found on inspect

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

My code:

```
Click Button        xpath://div[@class='ant-spin-container']//ancestor::button//span[contains(text(),'เพิ่มที่อยู่จัดส่ง')]
```

[image]

but can found this's element on inspect

[image]

Why this element not found on robot?

Comment: There are some very special characters there, maybe something cannot interpret those correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ofen It`s happening due to javascript loading too slow because for many reasons, such as slow internet connection or not optimized website. Because of that, before clicking the button, make sure that the robot sees it, using `Wait Until Page Contains Element` and then `Page Should Contain Button`